# Create as many pages as necessary for dynamic content

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I have a template which I'm filling with text. There is a header page, and several content pages after the header. Each content pages has two columns, and some logos and things at the bottom. I'm filling in the content dynamically with images and formatted text.

The number of pages is variable. How can I either duplicate content pages as needed, or (if I create a template with many pre-duplicated content pages) delete empty pages after filling in the content?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add a page with myDoc.pages.add(...) and then duplicate the content.
To remove pages: myPage.remove().

But the question is somewhat vague, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: The content on the pages is in two columns, and link between pages. I need to be able to append a very long block of text to the body content and have it span multiple pages. Do I need to link these body objects between pages?